# When using the XPath binding expression, can you get back InnerXml rather than InnerText?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding

I'm binding a control to an XmlDocument and using the "XPath" binding expression to output the data:

```
<div class="Bio"><%# XPath("Biography") %></div>
```

However, this returns the InnerText property of the "Biography" element, not the InnerXml.  This means it strips all inner tags from it, which is not what I want.

I looked through the XPathBinder object, but I can't find anyway to get it to return InnerXml rather than InnerText

Comment: Hi Daene.. I am looking for the same result now. Where you able to get this?

Comment: No, I was never able to alter this behavior. In reality, if you want InnerXml, that's because it contains markup (usually HTML), in which case it should probably be CDATA.

Comment: Thanks Deane. I somehow figured that out it is not possible. Thanks for pointing to me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding.XPath returns a value rather than a node, so you won't be able to get the InnerXml this way.  Can you define a method that returns SelectSingleNode(...).InnerXml instead?  If you define a method such as

```
public string GetInnerXml(object o)
{
    string val = String.Empty;
    XmlNode parent = o as XmlNode;
    XmlNode child = parent.SelectSingleNode("bob/fred");
    if (child != null)
        val = child.InnerXml;
    return val;
}
```

then invoke this from your binding expression, this ought to do the trick.  Code ought to be correct, but I haven't tested it so there may be errors.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but I'll make you the accepted answer since you at least told me I can't do what I want...